# unable to create double precision column in mysql

Tags: mysql, double, double-precision

I'm trying to create a table on mysql 5.6.16 on mac OS X (10.9). But somehow my installation is not recognizing double precision:

```
mysql> create table CUSTOM_FIELD_DEFIINITION (id bigint not null auto_increment, class varchar(255), decimalDigits bigint, defaultValue varchar(255), description varchar(255), displayFormat integer, fieldType integer, maxAllowed bigint, maxLength bigint, maxValue double precision, minLength bigint, minRequired bigint, minValue double precision, name varchar(255), owner_id bigint, regExpression varchar(255), scope varchar(255), sequence bigint, primary key (id));
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'maxValue double precision, minLength bigint, minRequired bigint, minValue double' at line 1

Comment: Use double (without precission word)

Comment: Found my problem!
one of the column names - maxValue- is actually a keyword in MySQL. Once I changed that column name (maxValueAllowed), the table got created no problems. even with double precision.

thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: You may want to post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using just `DOUBLE` instead of `DOUBLE PRECISION`? The `DOUBLE PRECISION` syntax is not always supported e.g. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69754

Comment: I changed to use double instead of double precision. Same error!

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem!
one of the column names - maxValue- is actually a keyword in MySQL. Once I changed that column name (maxValueAllowed), the table got created no problems. even with double precision.

thanks everyone for the help.